# Getting a return value from Lambda python

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to check if my lambda function is correctly working

```
rule_defs = {
'and': lambda r: (lambda d, r1, r2: match_rule(r1, d) and match_rule(r2, d),
                  [compile_rule(r[1]), compile_rule(r[2])])}
```

But when I try to run it

> ('and', 'a', 'a')

it just shows me something similiar of this

```
<function <lambda> at 0x023C68F0>, ['a', 'a']
```

Which as I understand is that i send in `['a'.'a']` into lambda d from which I would like a return value similar to `True`

Am I misunderstanding something basic?

*EDIT:*

The calling itself is not the problem but the return value being:

> function  at 0x023C68F0>, ['a', 'a']

instead of a value (i.e. *True*) and I'm not sure if that is the fault of my calling or the function itself

The call is done with a "help function"

```
calling(input)
    return rule_defs[input[0]](input)
```

(Python 2.7.X)

Comment: _"when I try to run it..."_ How exactly are you running it? I'm guessing `('and', 'a', 'a')` are your arguments, but that's not really sufficient to replicate your problem. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: ...what? Why are you nesting `lambda`s? What is it supposed to be doing? I would strongly suggest using a standlone function for this, so you can more easily test and document its behaviour.

Comment: You have two functions, the first which appears to take a list of rules and returns your function that you call with three arguments... there's a whole lot here that you're not showing us... like how exactly you call this thing.

Comment: @jonrshape The reason for nesting the lamdas was so that I "easily" could use a recursive function to go through a more nested and/or (or more advanced) functions e.g. ('and', ('or' ('something', 'a', 'b')))

Comment: @Kevin I pretty much just have a function which directly tries to call the rule_defs with the input 

>helpfunction(r)
>    return rule_defs[r[0]](r)

with the r being (('=', 'a', 'a'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you want your inner function to produce a tuple, you should also add another '(' after starting the inner lambda and close it just before.

Example -

```
rule_defs = {
'and': lambda r: (lambda d, r1, r2: (match_rule(r1, d) and match_rule(r2, d), [compile_rule(r[1]), compile_rule(r[2])]))}
```

Or if you were doing it correctly, and outer lambda intended to return a tuple of `(lambda, list)` , then to call the inner lambda use `rule_defs['and'](<parameter>)[0](<parameters>)`

When defining lambda within a lambda , you have to call first lambda with `()` and then again the second lambda with `()` .

So in your case , you would call your function with -

```
rule_defs['and'](r)(d, r1, r2)
```

Or you can assign it to a variable and then call that variable with the double paranthesis.

Example I tested with -

```
>>> rule_defs = { 'and': lambda r: (lambda d ,r1: print(d))}
>>> rule_defs['and'](1)(2,3)
2
```

Comment: The outer lambda returns a tuple, not just the inner lambda.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.

Comment: Thanks, understood the issue and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your lamba expression and then call it:

```
l = rule_defs['and']
l(d, r1, r2)
```

Replace the arguments with the value of your choice, then you will get the return value of the lambda function.

You can also do it at once:

```
rule_defs['and'](d, r1, r2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
rule_defs = { # define a dict
    'and': lambda r: ( # `lambda r` return a tuple: (lambda, list)
        lambda d, r1, r2: match_rule(r1, d) and match_rule(r2, d),
        [compile_rule(r[1]), compile_rule(r[2])]
    )
}
```

You should call your function by `rule_defs['and'](r)[0](d, r1, r2)`
In your case, it would be `rule_defs['and'](r)[0]('and', 'a', 'a')`

`rule_defs['and']` will get the function object `lambda r: (...)`

`rule_def['and'](r)` will call the `lambda r` function, and get the returned tuple

`rule_def['and'](r)[0]` get the index(0) of the returned tuple, e.g. function object `lambda d, r1, r2`

`rule_defs['and'](r)[0](d, r1, r2)` will call the `lambda d, r1, r2` function